# What is good practice to strore application config at RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, rmq

There is a set of same listeners that listens TCP ports and publishes received data to RabbitMQ queue. I need to have ability to configure listeners from backend at other side of the queue. There is no other connection to listeners except RMQ. What is the good practice to store application config within queue? Must it be a separate queue and exchange? Which parameters queue should have, where to read more? Thanks for any advising.

Comment: You won't be able to accomplish this because consumers consume; to configure, you would have to publish. You can't push configuration from a consumer to a publisher, unless you also have those publishers consuming an information stream that can be published by your backend.

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify. When Publisher starts it consumes config from a config queue. When Consumer has to configure it publishes a new config. In other words Consumers - programs that consume and sometimes publish, Publishers - programs which publishes and sometimes consumes.

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ doesn't store data. After message is consumed, it will be deleted. If you want to use rmq to send NOTIFICATION to consumers, that is doable. For configuration, my suggestion is zookeeper which also support listener on change.